# Passing req.body through Express middleware to routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm using the `body-parser` npm package to parse POST data in Application/JSON format and using a few different express routers to modularize the routes I'm creating. Here's the important info in my main server.js file:

### server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// I'm using a sessionId to identify a person in this dummy app instead of adding in authentication. So the API call is sent to http://localhost:5000/johndoe/todo
app.use('/:sessionId/todo', require('./routes/todoRoutes'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 9191;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

### todoRoutes.js:

```
var todoRouter = require('express').Router();

todoRouter.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("This is the post data:");
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = todoRouter;
```

`req.body` seems to be getting lost through the middleware; it logs `{}` to the console. **However**, on a whim I added the following to my bodyParsing middleware in `server.js`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json(), function (req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

And now it's passing `req.body` through to `todoRoutes.js`. (It now logs `{title: 'Testing'}`, etc. to the console like I need it to.)

What's going on here? And what's the best way to structure this so that it works the way it's supposed to? I'm new to Express, so I admit I could be structuring this all wrong.

Comment: Are you posting something (with a form or through ajax) to your route `/` ? Why do you `use` the route `/:sessionId/todo`? What should be contained in `req.body`?

Comment: I'm posting a "todo" item that looks like: `{
    "title": "Testing",
    "price": 15,
    "description": "This is a description",
    "completed": false
}` with Postman, so that's what _should_ be in `req.body`. I'm also doing GET, PUT, and DELETE (PUT and DELETE with an added `/:todoId` params added.) in todoRoutes.js. See my edit above for more info on how I'm using Postman.

Comment: I think you should post directly to a route instead of going through `app.use`.

Comment: From the examples I've found around the web, the way I'm doing it is a preferred way in order to modularize the code. I've got another set of routes that I also stuck on an `express.Router()` and I'm `use`ing those as middleware also. This way I don't need to put _all_ my routes in `server.js`.

Comment: You can require your route file using something like this `require('path/to/routes.js)(app)'` in your server file. And having everything wrapped up in `module.exports = function(app) { }` inside `routes.js`. Then you can require more files in `routes.js` while always passing the app variables and then decomposing routes and controllers into their own files.

Comment: I can do a Gist on github to show you what I mean.

Comment: That would be great, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: There is no downside that I know of of using app.use('path', routes) to assign routes to a specific set of pages. You might be able to set postman to set a JSON content-type (next to the 'raw' button is a dropdown that contains JSON).

Comment: Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/raphaelparent/b5736aad336654287288) ! :)

Comment: @AshleyB: That was exactly the problem. In fact it was already set and I had turned it off while I was messing with things. Good catch!

Comment: @RaphaelParent, thanks for the gist! I'll look it over. I also believe AshleyB is right though, that there aren't any downsides to using `app.use('path', routes)`, since that's the way I've seen it done it all the documentation and examples. But I'm sure I'll learn something about how Express works from your gist as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, nevermind. I was an idiot and found that the Content-Type Header of application/JSON got turned off in Postman (read: I must have turned it off at some point) and so the bodyParser was never being used.

Dammit.

Thanks for the help to those who responded!